# Yiic Grid view always giving live is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I know `live` has been deprecated. Now I am using Yii grid view and i have following code:

```
   $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'category-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        'title',
        array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
            'viewButtonUrl' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("/shop/category/view",
            array("id" => $data->category_id))',
            'updateButtonUrl' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("/shop/category/update",
            array("id" => $data->category_id))',
            'deleteButtonUrl' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("/shop/category/delete",
            array("id" => $data->category_id))',
        ),
    ),
));
```

On the browser it gives me error:

```
typeError: jQuery(...).live is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

jQuery('#category-grid a.delete').live('click',function() {
```

I am confused as i have searched the entire folder for .live function but i cant find it. Please help!

Comment: Which version of Yii are you using? I'm running 1.1.14 and the delete button does not use the live() method, it uses .on('click, '...')

Comment: @JoeMiller I think this might be the case. How can i replace live with on as i have searched the app but didn't find live

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because of the version of Yii. It may be using `.live()` which is deprecated.

One Possible solution can be you go to `yii/framework/zii/widgets/grid` and edit `CButtonColumn.php`

In this replace `.live()` by `.on()`

I think then it should work.

Comment: It Works..Was stuck in it for a long while. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

live function  of jquery is depreciated ... if u are using different version of jquery than the yii's built in ... show documentation of jquery for live() method ... use .on() or .delegate() method instead ... i'm not sure ...  but it can be a one solution if u are using other jquery version than the buit in...

from this page [Jquery live() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
**As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().**

**so it will not work forjquery version >= 1.7**

Answer (score 0):

You can re-write the default javascript action by doing this

```
        //I a'm commenting your delete url config
        //'deleteButtonUrl' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("/shop/category/delete",array("id" => $data->id))',
        'buttons' => array(
            'delete' => array(
                'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("/shop/category/delete",array("id" => $data->id))',
                'click' => 'js:function(evt)'
                . '{'
                . 'evt.preventDefault();'
                . 'alert("Your functionality Will Come here. Or Call a function");'
                . '}'
            ),
        )
```