# $(...).live is not a function - YII issue on Local server only - version 1.1.17 -dev

Tags: php, jquery, yii, live

I have already refer this question and its valid answer :

> [Yiic Grid view always giving live is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20634859/yiic-grid-view-always-giving-live-is-not-a-function)

And I can see that this has been already implemented in my YII structure.

Issue I am facing is every time I load YII view,it is giving me error that live() is not a function.

However, this happening only on local server but working fine on production.

Here by I am attaching image of console error :

[image: Image Of console error]

Strange is this is giving issue in admin.php file and there is not any live() written over there.

Any help will be much appreciated ?

Thanks

Comment: What version of jQuery? It was removed from 1.9.

Comment: Clear your browser cache and try once again please

Comment: Check if `$` is `jQuery` if you are using other libraries

Comment: Its all there. !! Thing is the same is working well on live but giving issue on Local server only !!

Comment: @ jeroen i have updated question with addition of Vesrion i am using

Answer (score 2):

Finally it is solved now.

I was using version 1.17 and from version 1.16 (After 1.15), they have updated their jquery so it was not working.

I have degraded my YII version from 1.17 to 1.15 and this is working fine now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try with .on() method instead of .live()

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 .live() function of jquery is depreciated  

    yii/framework/zii/widgets/grid/CButtonColumn.php

    edit below changes

    Replace .live() by .on()
```

Comment: refer:http://www.codeitive.com/0xHjkWWXXU/yiic-grid-view-always-giving-live-is-not-a-function.html